# Dark Mode macOS Sierra

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm trying to find a way to change the mode from light to dark in OS Sierra. I have this to change the settings:

```
CFPreferencesSetValue((CFStringRef)@"AppleInterfaceStyle", @"Dark", kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost);
```

And this to tell the OS to pick up on the change:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
               ^{CFNotificationCenterPostNotification(CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter(), (CFStringRef)@"AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification", NULL, NULL, true);}
               );
```

However, only the dock changes, not the notifications and menu bar. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Edit: If anyone has a list of the keys that plug into [this function](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1515525-cfpreferencessetvalue?language=objc#discussion) that would be helpful. Can't seem to find it on the apple docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a bit of a hacky way to accomplish this. Using applescript, it's pretty easy (and safe) to change the theme.

Script below:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell appearance preferences to set dark mode to not dark mode
end tell
```

Compile the script, add it to the xcodeproject and do a bit more research on how to run applescripts inside objective c.